# Unable to upload a file to google drive from a folder

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth

[This is how the file is being saved as, which is not what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfrJi.png)

[Directory as requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHzCy.png)

Creating a python function to save a file to google drive, but the file is in a separate folder and wont upload as intended.

When calling the function as

```
upload_to_drive("input.mp4")
```

It is understandably unable to find it as its not in the folder.

Ive tried

```
upload_to_drive("mp4/input.mp4")
```

The function actually runs and saves a file, but it doesn't save the actual input.mp4 file. Instead it saves the as "mp4/input.mp4".

If I try

```
upload_to_drive("input.mp4")
```

and place the file into the same directory it does actually work as intended, but this becomes a nightmare and crowds the directory.

I believe that it does read the file from the folder as it actually runs, it wouldn't otherwise. The "frankenfile" also is the same size as the real file.

I was unable to find anything specifying filepath when I skimmed Google Drive's Documentation.

Heres the code.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import sys

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.

def upload_to_drive(filename):
    """Uploads the specified file to Google Drive.



    Args:
        file_name (str): The name of the file to be uploaded.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]
    file_name = filename
    folder_id = "1FOsmjDwtzOem37SqfjfPFr2LEL4PErxL"
    arguments = ["-f", "-fs"]

    try:
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists("token.json"):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open("token.json", "w") as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())

        # build the Drive API client
        service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)

        # create a MediaFileUpload object for the file
        file = MediaFileUpload(file_name, mimetype="video/mp4", resumable=True)

        # create a file resource with metadata
        file_metadata = {"name": file_name, "parents": [folder_id]}

        # send a request to upload the file
        uploaded_file = (
            service.files()
            .create(body=file_metadata, media_body=file, fields="id")
            .execute()
        )

        print(
            f'File {file_name} sucessfully uploaded to Google Drive ID:({uploaded_file.get("id")})'
        )

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")

upload_to_drive("input.mp4")
```

Comment: About `place the file into the same directory it does actually work as intended`, what is `the same directory`? And, can I ask you about the relationship between `mp4/input.mp4` and the path of your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike 

Path for the file is "Desktop/project/mp4/input.mp4"
Which is why I tried passing in "mp4/input.mp4" since "main.py" is part of the same directory.
I've uploaded an image showcasing the directory.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, how about `upload_to_drive("./mp4/input.mp4")`?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for trying to help me. "upload_to_drive("./mp4/input.mp4")" just does the same thing that "upload_to_drive("/mp4/input.mp4")" does. It uploads the file as "./mp4/input.mp4". I'll upload an image of what its being saved as. These "frakenfiles" don't hold anything and when I try to fix the name it doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the reason for your new issue of `It uploads the file as "./mp4/input.mp4".`, is due to that you are using the inputted filename with the path is used as the filename of the Google Drive. If you don't want to use only the filename of `input.mp4`, how about separating the filename and path? By the way, what is `frakenfiles`?

Comment: "frankenfile" as in a Frankenstein, as in a file that "exists" but doesn't do as it should/work as it should. So sorry, it's what I've been calling them when I was talking to a friend.
I'm unsure how I would pass it in as file + path, I think I would need the os library? Haven't really used it that much, some more guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `frakenfiles`, I proposed a modified script by guessing your current situation. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your current situation and your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In your current situation, when you use `upload_to_drive("./mp4/input.mp4")`, the file content is correctly uploaded although the filename is not your expected value. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
def upload_to_drive(filename):
    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]
    file_name = os.path.basename(filename)
    folder_id = "1FOsmjDwtzOem37SqfjfPFr2LEL4PErxL"
    # arguments = ["-f", "-fs"] # It seems that this is not used in your showing script.
    try:
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists("token.json"):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            with open("token.json", "w") as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())

        service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
        file = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype="video/mp4", resumable=True)
        file_metadata = {"name": file_name, "parents": [folder_id]}
        uploaded_file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=file, fields="id").execute()
        print(f'File {file_name} sucessfully uploaded to Google Drive ID:({uploaded_file.get("id")})')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")


upload_to_drive("./mp4/input.mp4")
```

- By this modification, when `upload_to_drive("./mp4/input.mp4")` is run, `filename` and `file_name` are `./mp4/input.mp4` and `input.mp4`. And, the file of `./mp4/input.mp4` is uploaded as the filename of `input.mp4`.